# Rails loop through data fields error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to run a median calculation on data fields.

Each `Glaze` has the following decimal fields: `"k2o", "na2o", "cao", "bao", "mgo", "sro"`.

I want to write a method to calculate the median of each datafield using the entire database of `Glaze`s but I don't want to write individual methods for each `oxide`.

My plan was to loop through them using an array of the `oxide` names. I defined an array called `@oxides = ["k2o","n2o","cao","bao","mgo","sro"]`.

View:

```
<% @oxides.each do |oxide| %>
 <%= oxide %> median: <%= median(oxide) %><br/>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def median(oxide)
    g = Glaze.all
    array = g.map { |g| g.oxide.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
    sorted = array.sort
    len = sorted.length
    (sorted[(len - 1) / 2] + sorted[len / 2]) / 2.0
end
helper_method :median
```

This returns an error:

> unknown method 'oxide'

If I substitute `k2o` in place of `oxide` in the array then it works fine. I'm not familiar enough with variable types but I guess it is looking for a method because no `oxide` field exists.

How can I force it to look for the value of `oxide` so that I can easily loop through g.k2o...,g.na2o...,g.cao...etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Glaze` class does not have an instance method `oxide`, but instead has 5 methods `k2o`, `na2o`, `cao`, `bao`, `mgo`, `sro`. In

```
array = g.map { |g| g.oxide.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
```

the inner `g` is an instance of `Glaze`, so it will fail when you call `g.oxide`. If you want to do the same to all fields, i.e.

```
k2o_array = g.map { |g| g.k2o.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
na2o_array = g.map { |g| g.na2o.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
cao_array = g.map { |g| g.cao.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
bao_array = g.map { |g| g.bao.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
mgo_array = g.map { |g| g.mgo.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
sro_array = g.map { |g| g.sro.to_s.to_f.round(3) }
```

then you need [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
OXIDES = [:k2o, :na2o, :cao, :bao, :mgo, :sro]

def median(oxide)
  med = Hash.new
  OXIDES.each do |oxide|
    values = Glaze.all.map do |glaze|
      glaze.public_send(oxide).to_s.to_f.round(3)
    end
    values.sort!
    len = values.length
    med[oxide] = (values[(len - 1) / 2] + values[len / 2]) / 2.0
  end
  return values
end
helper_method :median
```

which will give you

```
{:k2o=>1.111, :na2o=>2.222, :cao=>3.333, :bao=>4.444, :mgo=>5.556, :sro=>6.667}
```

Note that I store the oxide list in a [constant](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/constants.html) instead of an [instance variable](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html) because it never changes.